# Was I extremely rude or is the chat community just this toxic?

Tags: discussion, questions

All right, this may seem like a bit of an over-reaction, but something just doesn't seem 'proper' in this situation.

- I join X programming chat room with the intent of asking a relevant
  and education question.
- I hang around for maybe 20 minutes, view the chat etiquette page,
  make sure that I'm not being rude by that room's standards.
- I paste the code I would like help with into an online engine.
- Realise that my code isn't functioning properly in the online engine.
- Fire off a quick question in the chat explaining above situation.
- This chat ensues:

ME: Hi guys, just trying to throw my XXX into YYY so I can actually ask my question, but for some reason, regardless of the version of ZZZ I import, my ZZZ functionality on my XXX refuses to appear

> ChatBot: @ME automatic post for first time comment about looking at rules, be polite ect.
>
> RoomHost: Flagged.
>
> Person1: @RoomHost going to flag for mod attention; I think someone needs to talk to this idiot
>
> RoomHost: Moderator has already seen it.
> he's one of the closers.
> and the comments have already been purged once.

---

Now, I've never been in this room before, I waited to ensure no one else was being helped before interjecting and asking my own question, no one had spoke in over 20 minutes besides me, so I'm sure the comments were directed at me.

Also, the chat's recent history consisted of a spam of memes and GiFs, rather than users helping each other, so I don't see how trying to get help should be shot down so quickly and harshly when the whole point of the room is to get help?

I guess my question is, are certain chat rooms really just that toxic or have I somehow offended people?

I've blanked out usernames, and other descriptive features so that the users I'm pointing out can't be traced back from this. I'm not out to cause more grief or offend anyone.

Edit: people aren't satisfied unless I name the culprits, so here's a transcript: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17/2015/5/1/21-24

Comment: Can't be entirely sure without seeing the transcript, but... Ya, chat can be fairly toxic. Depends on the room, some are better than others.

Comment: So what you guys are telling me is, because I'm a new member of the overflow community and have posted a question or two that may be considered stupid by people who have spent years learning these coding languages that I have literally picked up in the last month. That in a community where teaching and helping are the foundation making this whole system work, that it is acceptable to demean a person because they think a legitimate question is stupid?

Comment: Looking at the transcript...those users weren't talking to or about you. They were talking about an entirely unrelated question and your message was in the middle of the conversation. Your perception that you are "sure the comments were directed at [you]" looks, frankly, rather misguided from the way I read it.

Comment: @BenBowen Chat rooms are a very different place from the main site. Each one is different (sometimes dramatically) and they each have their own rules and regulations to abide by; it's important to read those rules (which can usually be found in the description and to understand what you're getting yourself into. Yes; certain chat rooms can be that "toxic," and they're focused on different topics. What you were asking may not have been fit to that room's particular culture, but in general, without seeing the context of the conversation and knowing the room, it's hard to say much more than that.

Comment: @eldarerathis  As I said in my main post, the users that made comments hadn't been talking beforehand and these posts came in less than a minute after I made mine, considering no one had been talking in the room for over 20 minutes beforehand.

Comment: @AstroCB Also in my main post, I did read the rules, my questions were appropriate to the room topic, the tools I was using to share my code are considered industry standard and that is the entire conversation, I went idle after that and no one talked for a large portion of time after, either.

Comment: Add the two comments prior to yours into your question, so everyone can see the full context. It makes it abundantly obvious they were talking about another question and not about you, and I would be willing to bet that others will read it the same way I am. You are reading into something that simply is not there.

Comment: Or just link to the transcript. It's not like it's hard to find anyway.

Comment: @BenBowen: they were talking about a JS question on SO. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995513/how-to-call-a-prototype-with-array-like-syntax). You might not see the link, but they all participated in closing/commenting, might not have been apparent from the chat transcript only (and prob. some comments got deleted by now too). There's no such thing as "closing" a chat message. You're misinterpreting the whole thing.

Comment: How do you read "If that's the case, it's unfortunate, but you kind of have to expect it" and take that to mean "it's acceptable to demean a person"? I think you're getting overly emotional and it's clouding your reading comprehension.

Comment: @BenBowen As a fairly new user to that chatroom myself I've not found it to be very toxic or offensive. It's by all means possible to get into arguments there but from my ~2 weeks of lurking/participating I don't find that to be the norm at all. Also, they seem to to come down hard on people who misuse flags, and if anyone flagged that first message of yours I am 100% they'd be upset about the flag and not your message. Not all questions in there get answered, you can try again if you want but just like an SO question there's no guarantee anyone will have the time/energy to look at it.

Comment: @BenBowen As an aside, on jsfiddle there's a dropdown top left of the editor that lets you select how to include external libs, I think it defaults to onload. Try including it in <head>.

Answer (score 33):

AS THE PERSON WHO SAID

> @rlemon going to flag for mod attention; I think someone needs to talk to this idiot

Let me clarify what was happening. We were talking about [this abomination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995513/how-to-call-a-prototype-with-array-like-syntax#comment48112777_29995513) of a question.

The comments, now [cleansed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23048387#23048387), by the OP (of the linked question) were extremely rude and uncalled for. Here are a few:

> @SterlingArcher don't mean to be offensive , but get your eyes checked , where do those two questions speak of how to call a prototype function using square brakets ?? (sorry my JS terminology is bad !)
>
> @royhowie , from your point of view , not mine ! also, get your clown-face off my question , if you have nothing constructive to offer !
>
> @royhowie , u call scarcism help ?? ((sorry my JS terminology is bad !)) ?

The OP of that question did not understand what civil conversation was. Because we were closing his question as a duplicate (which it clearly is), he became heated/offended and lashed out.

As other people have pointed out, you misread the conversation. We weren't talking about you. Sorry if your question was never answered; it probably got lost in the moment, since the linked question was rather frustrating.

Feel free to come back and ask it again. (Just ping me and I'll go through the problem with you.)

Also, I feel it unfair to call the chatroom `really just that toxic`. I'd like to think (most) people in SO chatrooms are nice and reasonable people.

Comment: What _are_ you supposed to call scarcism, anyway?

Answer (score 15):

Based on the transcript, it looks like you have misunderstood what happened. It also seems that your timeline is incorrect.

#### Timeline (as seen in the transcript)

- 11:35pm UTC: One minute before your post a comment was linked that indicated inappropriate behavior on a question. At this time, two room owners are also pinged
- 11:36 pm UTC: You post your question and the bot replies telling you to read the rules and just ask your question
- Still 11:36 pm UTC: One of the pinged room owners indicates that they flagged. Presumably this was directed at the message from 11:35. This is confirmed by the message a minute later at 11:37pm that says a moderator is looking at the question.

---

The entire episode you described took place in less than two minutes. It appears you simply had bad timing and posted in the middle of a discussion about inappropriate behavior on the site. Nothing I'm reading in the transcript appears to be directed at your *one* message.

I don't see you, or your comment, mentioned anywhere in the transcript. It seems that you were simply ignored. Like the bot said:

> [J]ust ask your question, and if anyone's free and interested they'll help.

You didn't ask a question. You simply stated you can't get jQuery to work when making a fiddle. If you want help in the chat, I suggest fleshing out the problem a little bit more. Perhaps a link to the fiddle would be helpful?